# No bean introspection available for type [class java.lang.String]

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, micronaut

I have the entity defined as below

```
@Slf4j
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "BOL_ACTOR")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Introspected
@Embeddable
public class BolActor implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name = "BOL_ID")
private String billOfLading;

@Id
@Column(name="ACTOR_ID")
private String inbondActor;
}
```

Whenever i'm trying to fetch the entity by any id.. using the repository
i'm getting the following exception

```
io.micronaut.core.beans.exceptions.IntrospectionException: No bean introspection available for type [class java.lang.String]. Ensure the class is annotated with io.micronaut.core.annotation.Introspected
```